# Self hosted GitLab pages not showing at Setting page even if my CI building public/ folder runs successfully

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I want to use GitLab pages at my self hosted GitLab server, this is my `.gitlab-ci.yml` file

```
image: node:12.16.1-alpine3.10

before_script:
  - pwd
  - which nodejs
  - nodejs -v
  - which npm
  - npm -v

pages:
  cache:
    paths:
      - node_modules/
  script:
    - rm -rf package-lock.json
    - npm install
    - npm run storybook:build # This will build my website at public folder
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - public
  only:
    - master
```

My CI runs successfully, I can even download the artifacts that contain my public folder.

But I didn't see `Setting/Pages` option, so I don't know what is the public URL of my website.

What configuration did I miss?

Comment: If you're not seeing `Settings/Pages` on your self-hosted server, have you enabled the [pages administration](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/pages/)?

Comment: I think I'm not, thank you.